# How to get number of occurrences of a month from a list of dates in java

Tags: java, list, count, stream, monthcalendar

Java : I have a list of String which holds Date column data from database.
I want the count of each month .

Say I have data :
2021-07-01
2021-08-20
2021-08-25
2021-09-05
2022-01-06
2022-06-07

I want to retrieve value 1 for July,2 for August, 1 for September, 1 for January, 1 for June .

How can I use stream API to achieve this? Or any other method to retrieve vthis data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine array of dates and sum values per month in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480926/combine-array-of-dates-and-sum-values-per-month-in-java)

Comment: @PM77-1 [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32480926/642706) is quite similar. But this Question here wants only a count of each month’s occurrence count, woh no extraneous number to sum. So I think this Question deserves its own solution.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
List
.of( "2021-07-01", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-25", "2021-09-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-06-07" )
.stream()
.map( input -> LocalDate.parse( input ) )      // Parse each element as a `LocalDate` object, for a new stream.
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy( date -> 
                   YearMonth :: from ,         // Extract a `YearMonth` from each `LocalDate` as the key.
                   Collectors.counting()       // Count occurrences.
    )
)                                              // Return a `Map`.
```

## Details

Make example data.

```java
List< String > inputs = List.of( "2021-07-01", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-25", "2021-09-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-06-07" );
```

Make a stream of those inputs. Parse each element as a `LocalDate` object, for a new stream. Produce a key-value `Map < YearMonth , Integer >` object by extracting a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) from each `LocalDate` as the key, and summing one as a count of occurrences for the value.

```java
Map< YearMonth , Integer > monthCounts = 
    inputs
        .stream()
        .map( input -> LocalDate.parse( input ) )      // Parse each element as a `LocalDate` object, for a new stream.
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy( date -> 
                           YearMonth :: from  ,        // Extract a `YearMonth` from each `LocalDate` as the key.
                           Collectors.counting()       // Count occurrences.
            )
        )                                              // Return a `Map`.
;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/37D6y6).

> {2021-09=1, 2021-08=2, 2021-07=1, 2022-06=1, 2022-01=1}

### Sort by year-month: `NavigableMap`

You might want to keep the entries in your resulting map sorted by the `YearMonth` keys. If so:

- Change your declared map type from `Map` to [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface.
- Add an argument for [`TreeMap :: new`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) to instantiate an objecting implementing `NavigableMap`.

```java
NavigableMap < YearMonth, Long > monthCounts =
        inputs
                .stream()
                .map( input -> LocalDate.parse( input ) )
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                YearMonth :: from ,
                                TreeMap::new,
                                Collectors.counting()
                        )
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a process to allow you to get your desired goal using Streams and Lambdas.

1. Parse your dates into an Array of LocalDates.
2. Define a Predicate for your criteria.
3. Filter your Stream using your Predicate and get the count().

   ```
    String[] dates = { "2021-07-01", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-25", "2021-09-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-06-07" };
    LocalDate[] localDates = new LocalDate[dates.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
        localDates[i] = LocalDate.parse(dates[i]);
    }

    Predicate<LocalDate> month = localDate -> localDate.getMonth().equals(Month.AUGUST);

    long count = Arrays.stream(localDates).filter(month).count();
   ```